# Getting NullPointerException while mocking in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

Am trying to write a Junit Test case for one of the class. But getting error while trying to do it,

Test class looks like below -

```
public class IntegratorClassTest{
    @InjectMocks    
    IntegratorClass integratorClass;

    @Mock
    RequestClass requestClass;

    @Mock
    ContentList contentResponse;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void getCmsOffersTest()throws Exception{
        ContentService contentService = Mockito.mock(ContentService.class);
        RequestClass requestClass = Mockito.mock(RequestClass.class);
        ContentList contentResponse = getContentList();
        when(contentService.getContentCollection()).thenReturn(contentResponse);

        Validator validator = Mockito.mock(Validator.class);
        List<OfferDetails> offerList = new ArrayList<OfferDetails>();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(validator).validateData(offerList);

        List<OfferDetails> offerListResult = integratorClass.getCmsOffers(contentService, requestClass);
        assertTrue(offerListResult.size()>0);
    }
}
```

And the implementation class looks something like below -

```
public class IntegratorClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegratorClass.class);

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;

    public List<OfferDetails> getCmsOffers(ContentService contentService,RequestClass requestClass)throws Exception{
        LOGGER.info("Entered method getCmsOffers to get the list of offers from CMS");
        List<OfferDetails> offerList = new ArrayList<OfferDetails>();
        ContentList contentResponse = null;
        try 
        {
            contentResponse = contentService.getContentCollection();
            offerList = getOfferListFromCmsResponse(contentResponse, requestClass);

            LOGGER.info("Total number of active offers we got from CMS are -" + offerList.size());
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = PromotionalOffersUtilities.createErrorResponse("500", e.getMessage(),"Getting error while fetching content from CMS - getCmsOffers", ErrorResponse.Type.ERROR);
            LOGGER.error("Getting error while fetching content from CMS with Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new ServiceException(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        //failing here
        validator.validateData(offerList);
        LOGGER.info("Exiting method getCmsOffers");

        return offerList;
    }
}
```

When I ran it in debug mode am error for the line `validator.validateData(offerList);`.

It is returning "`NullPointerException`".

Comment: You're creating a mock Validator, but the class under test doesn't use that mocked validator, sice you don't inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `Validator` when mocking dependencies so that it will be injected into the subject under test

```
@Mock
Validator validator;
```

Also when arranging the behavior of the `validator` use an argument matcher for the invoked member as the current setup wont match because they will be comparing different instances when exercising the test.

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(validator).validateData(any(List<OfferDetails>.class));
```

You are manually mocking the other dependencies within the test method so they are not needed out side of that

The test now becomes

```
public class IntegratorClassTest{
    @InjectMocks
    IntegratorClass integratorClass;

    @Mock
    Validator validator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getCmsOffersTest()throws Exception{
        //Arrange
        ContentService contentService = Mockito.mock(ContentService.class);
        RequestClass requestClass = Mockito.mock(RequestClass.class);
        ContentList contentResponse = getContentList();
        Mockito.when(contentService.getContentCollection()).thenReturn(contentResponse);

        Mockito.doNothing().when(validator).validateData(any(List<OfferDetails>.class));

        //Act
        List<OfferDetails> offerListResult = integratorClass.getCmsOffers(contentService, requestClass);

        //Assert
        assertTrue(offerListResult.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine now, also I have used like below -

Mockito.doNothing().when(validator).validateData(Mockito.anyList());